# What can I do to fix my AWS CDK installation?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I may of somehow corrupted my AWS CDK system package. When attempting to `cdk synth` or `cdk list` I am getting the following traceback:

```bash
$ cdk list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
    import aws_cdk as cdk
  File "/path/to/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aws_cdk/__init__.py", line 1285, in <module>
    from .cloud_assembly_schema import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'AssetManifestOptions' from 'aws_cdk.cloud_assembly_schema' (/path/to/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aws_cdk/cloud_assembly_schema/__init__.py)

Subprocess exited with error 1
```

My .venv packages are as such:

```bash
$ pip3 freeze | grep aws
aws-cdk-lib==2.59.0
aws-cdk.asset-awscli-v1==2.2.49
aws-cdk.asset-kubectl-v20==2.1.1
aws-cdk.asset-node-proxy-agent-v5==2.0.38
aws-cdk.assets==1.187.0
aws-cdk.aws-cloudwatch==1.187.0
aws-cdk.aws-ec2==1.187.0
aws-cdk.aws-events==1.187.0
aws-cdk.aws-iam==1.187.0
aws-cdk.aws-kms==1.187.0
aws-cdk.aws-logs==1.187.0
aws-cdk.aws-networkfirewall==1.187.0
aws-cdk.aws-s3==1.187.0
aws-cdk.aws-s3-assets==1.187.0
aws-cdk.aws-ssm==1.187.0
aws-cdk.cloud-assembly-schema==1.187.0
aws-cdk.core==1.187.0
aws-cdk.cx-api==1.187.0
aws-cdk.region-info==1.187.0
```

My system wide packages are as such:

```bash
user@host:$ deactivate
user@host:$ pip3 freeze | grep aws
user@host:$
```

The difference between the last working state and today was that I tried to initialize another CDK project in a different directory. After initialization the other CDK project I began to face the same problem.

```bash
$ cdk --version
2.59.0 (build b24095d)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You seem to be mixing CDK v1 and v2 dependencies.  See the [Updating dependencies and imports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/migrating-v2.html#migrating-v2-v1-upgrade-dependencies) section of the [migration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/migrating-v2.html).

Comment: Also check if the new installation added anything in your path. as pointed earlier looks like issue of cdk v1 and v2